# jonckheere.test in R - alternative hypothesis?

Tags: r

I'm using `jonckheere.test` from the clinfun package to evaluate whether there is a trend across groups in my data.  More specifically, I have ~60 samples that can be grouped into one of 5 categories.

I see that one parameter for the call is alternative with the default being 'two.sided'.  My initial interpretation of this is H0 = No trend, up or down, with the H1 = Some trend, either up or down.  But in reading the documentation I see this:

```
alternative    means are monotonic (two.sided), increasing, or decreasing
```

From this it looks like for the two.sided version, H0 = Some trend with H1 = no trend.

Am I reading this right and just having trouble thinking about it in reverse?

Comment: Alternative is != 0, so H_0 = 0.

Comment: If you are using other packages you should always mention those in your question.  Jonckheere.test is not in base R.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The package I'm using for Jonckheere.test is clinfun.  I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading it correctly.  If you specify "two.sided" the alternative is that the means are monotonic in some direction.  This could mean that the means are increasing or that they are decreasing - either one works.